# array_unique() in php simple html dom

Tags: php, html, arrays, simple-html-dom, array-unique

I wrote the code blow to get all **unique** links from a url:

```
include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element){ 
  $input = array($element->href = $element->href . '<br />');
  print_r(array_unique($input));}
```

but I really can't understand why it shows the duplicated links too!
is there any problem with the function `array_unique` and `simple html dom`?
and there's another thing I guess is related to the problem: when you execute this you see all of the link that it extracted are in one key I mean this :

```
array(key  => all values)
```

Is there any one who can solve this?

Comment: `$element->href = $element->href` what's this code for?

Comment: And you're overwriting `$input` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want it more like this:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) { 
    $temp[] = $element->href;
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r(array_unique($temp), true) . '</pre>';
```